# A function f(x) satisfies $f(x) = \sin x +\int^x_0 f'(t)(2\sin t-\sin^2t)dt$, then find f(x)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Problem :

A function $f$ satisfies $f\left(x\right) = \sin x +∫^x_0 f'\left(t\right)\left(2\sin t-\sin ^2t\right)dt$, then find $f\left(x\right)$.

My approach :

Differentiating both sides we get :

$f'\left(x\right) = \cos x +f'\left(x\right)\left(2\sin x-\sin ^2x\right) $

Using Leibnitz's rule : $\frac{d}{dx}\left(∫^{\psi\left(x\right)}_{\phi\left(x\right)} f\left(t\right)dt\right) = \frac{d}{dx}\left\{\psi\left(x\right)\right\} f\left(\psi\left(x\right)\right) -\frac{d}{dx}\left\{\phi\left(x\right)\right\} f\left(\phi \left(x\right)\right)$

Could you please guide me further as it seems application of Leibnitz's rule  is incorrect. Please guide will be of great help thanks.

Comment: I think it's correct. Now write $$f'(x) = \frac{cos x}{1-2sinx+ sin^2 x}=\frac{cosx}{(sinx-1)^2}$$ and then integrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You applied Newton-Leibniz rule correctly.

$$f'(x) = \frac{cos x}{1-2sinx+ sin^2 x}=\frac{cosx}{(sinx-1)^2}$$ and then integrate.

$$f(x)=\frac{-1}{sinx-1}+c$$

From given initial equation $f(0)=0$,
which gives $c=-1$.

Hence, $$f(x)=\frac{-1}{sinx-1}-1$$

Answer (score 2):

You get

$$f'(x)=\frac{\cos x}{1-2\sin x+\sin^2x}$$

To integrate it use $u=\sin x$

$$\frac{1}{1-\sin x}$$

Now insert $x=0$ (in the original equation) to find the constant

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-\sin x}-1$$